# send() and puts() are mixed together, (programming a FTP server in C)

Tags: c, sockets, ftp, send, puts

I'm making a FTP server in C. At the client side I'm using FileZilla. My code so far contains only the handshaking part.

The problem I've got is that the strings I print out for the terminal are sent to FileZilla.
My question is how can I keep these two seperated, i've tried a couple of things, but none of them give the correct result.

This is only a part of my code, but for my question is this the useful part:

```
while (FOREVER){
    addr_size = sizeof their_addr;

    newfd = accept(listener, (struct sockaddr*) &their_addr, &addr_size);
    if (newfd == -1){
        perror("accept");
        continue;
    }
    if ((send(newfd, "220 JEDI FTP is ready", 50, 0)) <= 0)
        perror("error sending");

    puts("connection established");
    puts("waiting for user & connection");
  while (!login){
        // username
        if (!user){
            if ((recv(newfd, buffer, BUFFCON, 0)) <= 0){
                puts("error receiving username");

            }
            else{

                if (strstr(buffer, "USER") != NULL){

                    if (strstr(buffer, name) != NULL){

                        send(newfd, "331 password required", 50, 0);
                        puts("username correct");

                        user = 1;
                    }
                    else{
                        puts("username incorrect");
                        send(newfd, "430 username incorrect", 50, 0);
                    }//else
                }//if
            }//else
        }//if user
```

And this is the output in FileZilla:

- Status:   Adres bepalen van localhost
- Status:   Verbinden met [::1]:21...
- Status:   Verbinding aangemaakt, welkomstbericht afwachten...
- Antwoord: 220 JEDI FTP is ready
- Commando: USER yoda
- Antwoord: connection established
- Fout: Kan niet verbinden met server

So instead of sending "331 password required" it sends "connection established"

Hope you can help me with this, Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're not doing any weird stdout redirection when running the command, are you? How exactly are you running it?

Comment: As far as I know, i don't do anything strange with stdout.THe connection is made via localhost. And my code is executed in VS2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `len` parameter for `send` is too large. `send` has no concept of null-terminated strings; it only works with raw sequences of bytes. So the call `send(newfd, "220 JEDI FTP is ready", 50, 0)` sends the string `"220 JEDI FTP is ready"`, and then whatever happens to come in memory after it. Technically, this is *undefined behavior*, so literally *anything* could happen (usually a segfault). In your case, because constant literal strings are usually stored sequentially in memory, `send` is reading the given string, and then reading a different string after it.

What you want to do is *only* send the exact string (which, by the way, needs the CR-LF sequence `\r\n` after each command). No more, no less. You can implement a `sends` function to send a string like so:

```
ssize_t sends(int fd, const char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    return send(fd, str, len, 0);
}
```

Also note that the data sent does *not* include the null-terminator, because the TCP packet specifies the size of the string.

Comment: The FTP protocol spec dictates that a CRLF `\r\n` must be used for line breaks on commands and responses.